# Got "no matching function" from GCC

Tags: c++, templates

Why this simple code does not work?

```
template<class U>
class retype 
{ 
    typedef U type; 
};

class object
{
public:
    template<class U>
    int create(typename retype<U>::type p)
    {
        return 4;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int n = object().create(5);

    return 0;
}
```

Got this error while compiling with GCC:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘object::create(int)’
```

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You're relying on template argument deduction from function argument. But the function template argument cannot be deduced, because that is a non-deducible context.

More specifically, the template parameter `U` cannot be deduced even if `retype<U>::type` is `int`.  Because there might be a specialization of `retype` defined as:

```
template<>
struct retype<X>
{
      typedef int type;
};
```

So you see, given `retype<U>::type` is `int`, the template parameter `U` can be `X` as well.

In fact, there might be more than one such specializations, all of which may define `type` to be `int`. So there is no one-one relationship. The compiler cannot *uniquely* deduce `U`.

Comment: Why non-deducible context? U type is int, retype<U>::type is int too - very easy to deduce

Comment: And in fact, this is a common approach to preventing deduction (although you'd usually see `std::identity<T>::type`)

Comment: @user1941152: No, I say, `U` is `X`, as shown in my answer. In fact, there can be many such `X`, `Y`, or `Z` if there are more specializations. The compiler cannot uniquely deduce `U`.

Comment: @user1941152: For deduction, you have to go the other direction.  `retype<U>::type` should be `int`.  What is `U`?  Well, you would have to check every single specialization of `retype`.  So the language designers simply said deduction won't take place in this fashion.